# From php to smarty line of code?

Tags: php, html, smarty

So I have a php line of code that I'm trying to convert to Smarty. I've been able to convert the variable but the small syntax before it I'm having trouble with. Bellow are both syntax, how do I add the link_it within Smarty? Thanks in advance.

**PHP Code**

```
<span class="commentText" >
    '.link_it($com['comment']).'
</span>
```

**Smarty code**

```
<span class="commentText" >
    {$com.comment}   
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call your PHP function as a [modifier](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifiers.tpl) so long as security isn't enabled.

```
<span class="commentText">
    {$com.comment|link_it}
</span>
```